# Is there every a reason to use thread affinity when there are more threads being used than ones specified/reserved?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am working with Rust but this question would also apply to many other situations.

Suppose you have M available vCPUs and N threads (including the main thread) to schedule, and that N > M. Each thread does approximately equal amounts of work.

Is there any good reason then to pin threads to specific cores? I've written a number of toy benchmarks and it seems like the answer is no, as I cannot make a program under these assumptions that performs better with thread affinity; in fact, it always does much worse.

Answer (score 0):

if your application is working on a system with a lot of cores and heavily relies on the core cache, a context switch will be too expensive, so pinning tasks to cores reduces the context switches and improves throughput.

but in an "average pc" running plain RAM-bound tasks then your OS scheduler will be much better at load balancing the cores than you ever will.

pinning threads to cores is also useful if you care about latency instead of throughput, in a heavily loaded system if you have a time-critical task then you want it to have its own core which won't be contented by other tasks on the system, hence it makes sense to pin it to a certain core, an example will be an in-memory Database that needs to responds to request in under a millisecond latency.

so the answer is, it's only useful for certain apps.

Comment: Okay, so are you saying that if there are M vCPUs and N = M + K threads, it could ever be beneficial to assign M - 1 threads to specific vCPUs, and 1 vCPU for the remaining K threads?

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos this answer's sole purpose is to show that it's not about `whether` and more about `when`, yes it will "sometimes" be beneficial to assign M-1 threads to specific vCPUs, but it depends on the workload, and you'll have to use a better dynamic task dispatch mechanism to ensure you don't end up with idle cores. in the end you only care about how much work you can get done as fast as possible.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos obviously having unbalanced task distribution on cores means that you have different kinds of tasks running on each thread and you want to enforce a priority on some of them, but if you are just running a bunch of tasks with no priority or the same priority on all of them then , NO, you shouldn't use core affinity, and you might just use a lower number of threads to start with.

Comment: So it can be helpful to assign `M-1` threads to specific vCPUs even if all the threads are doing the same kind of work and the same amount of work?

Comment: FYI I only care about latency

Comment: Can you come up with a toy example of a thread for which this would be the case?